# “Reservation for” vs. “reservation at”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm trying to check if this sentence is correct.

> Is this reservation for the Holiday Inn?

Or, should I use

> Is this reservation at the Holiday Inn?

Comment: You'd have a reservation _at_ the Holiday Inn _for_ a time or duration.

Comment: You can also have a reservation _for_ dinner, but it's still _at_ the restaurant.

Comment: Both are perfectly okay to me, but in any given context I'd usually prefer one or the other. Not necessarily exactly reflecting the distinctions made in the two existing answers, but something along those lines. If I said *"I made a reservation **at** the Holiday Inn"* it would more strongly imply I did this *while I was there*, whereas if I used ***for*** that might imply I did it from somewhere else (perhaps by phone).

Answer (score 3):

If the reservation has not been mentioned, I'd use *at*:

> We have a reservation at the Haliday Inn.

But if the venue of a reservation already referenced or noticed is being queried, I'd use *for*:

> Is that reservation for the Hillydale Inn?

Answer (score 1):

For the location of the reservation, *"at"* should be used.

Answer (score -1):

The second is certainly correct.

The first isn't technically wrong, it's certainly *for* the purpose of a stay there, but it would be unusual enough to sound strange.

The first could be preferred in a few cases. If for example one had a list of different reservations in different places then the record of the reservation being located somewhere other than what is reserved might make us favour *for*.

But in general, use *at* for the place (hotel, restaurant, resort) and *for* for the time, duration or purpose ("two nights", "eight o' clock", "lunch").